# TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object while using pool.map over a method

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping, multitasking

I have a list of `Iterables` and I want to use `pool.map` with an instance method. The problem is that the mentioned method doesn't run and I get the below error.

code:

```
def return_brands_of_product(self,product):
        if product['_source']['brand_id'] != "" and product['_source']['brand_id'] not in self.brands_ids:
            self.brands.append({"brand_id":product['_source']['brand_id'],"name":product['_source']['brand'][0]['name']
                                ,"en_name":product['_source']['brand'][0]['en_name']})
            self.brands_ids.append(product['_source']['brand_id'])

instance = GenerateBrandsFromCategories(cat['_id'])
products = instance.return_products_by_cat_id()
pool.map(instance.return_brands_of_product, products)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fetch_brands_from_products.py", line 165, in <module>
    main()
  File "fetch_brands_from_products.py", line 161, in main
    a=pool.map(ins, products)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

Comment: I can't be sure but I don't think you are allowed to pass class methods into multiprocessing because it would lose the class it referenced and would no longer make any sense. I think you will need to pass the information you need to use into the function separately and figure out how to add the returned data to your class. You are allowed to pass a method decorated with `@staticmethod` because it doesn't need a class reference, but this does mean you will need to pass in all of the data in the arguments and get the values back from the function's return.

Comment: I need self in my code body because of some variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in some code I was writing.  The easiest workaround was:

```
def runner(product):
    instance = GenerateBrandsFromCategories(cat['_id']) 
    instance.return_brands_of_product(product)

...
pool.map(runner, products)
```

In my case, creating the instance anew for each thread was cheap.